# Get static field through reflection without triggering initialization?

Tags: java, reflection

We have a WAR application which uses a third-party library that creates a threadpool with a running thread as a static field of one of its internal classes. When we undeploy the WAR, this thread continues running. To work around this, I want to run some code during undeployment which uses reflection to access the private static field and shut down the thread pool.

The threadpool is created in a static initializer for the class. It's possible the class in question hasn't been loaded or initialized when our shutdown code runs, and I don't want the shutdown code to initialize the class just to shut it down again if I can avoid that.

I can use the three-argument form of `Class.forName()` to get the class without initializing it. However, after getting the `Field` that I want, getting the value of the field still triggers the class to be initialized. I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

Here is some example code:

```
package scratch;
public class A {
    private static final String field;
    static {
        System.out.println("A initializing");
        field = "I'm initialized!";
    }
}

package scratch;
public class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // var a = new A();
        try {
            System.out.println("B starting");
            var clazz = Class.forName("scratch.A", false, B.class.getClassLoader());
            System.out.println("B got class");
            var field = clazz.getDeclaredField("field");
            System.out.println("B got field");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println("B set accessible");
            var value = field.get(null);
            System.out.println("B got value '" + value + "'");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this code produces this output:

```
B starting
B got class
B got field
B set accessible
A initializing
B got value 'I'm initialized!'
```

The call to `Field.get()` triggers initialization of the class.

I just want to avoid initializing the class (if it's not already initialized) in the process of accessing this field to shut it down. Is there any way to avoid fetching the class if it's not already loaded? Or to test whether it's initialized before fetching the field? Or to fetch the value of the field without triggering initialization?

Comment: Does the thread pool use distinctive thread names? Then, you can first check whether a thread with a name indicating the existence of the pool exists.

Comment: @Holger The threadpool does use a distinctive thread name. But there are other deployments in this tomcat instance using the same third-party library. So there are threads with the distinctive name belonging to other deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Static block code executes only once during the class loading.
At this point:

```java
    static {
        System.out.println("A initializing");
        field = "I'm initialized!";
    }
```

class is not initialized, but just loaded into JVM. You can't get information of class via reflection if it is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to fix this is to not tie your initialization to class loading. And that's fine, because that's a bad idea anyway. So rewrite your class:

```
public class A {
    private static A LATEST_INSTANCE;
    private String field;
    
    private A() {
        System.out.println("A initializing");
        field = "I'm initialized!";
        LATEST_INSTANCE = this;
    }
}
```

Now you can access the `LATEST_INSTANCE` field and do whatever you want to its state. You don't even need reflection! You can create static methods to access and access or initialize the instance(s), whatever you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual class that I'm targeting is a third-party dependency. Rewriting the class isn't that straightforward.